# prop_search with a custom PropertyGroup

Tags: python, scripting, properties

I want the user to be able to select some data from a `CollectionProperty`

```
audioFiles = CollectionProperty(type=AudioFileNameGroup)
```

holding data of a custom `PropertyGroup` type:

```
class AudioFileNameGroup(types.PropertyGroup):
    fileName = StringProperty(name="File Name", subtype='FILE_NAME')
```

To enable the selection for the user, in a panel I'm using `prop_search` on that:

```
navStateCol.prop_search(obj, "audioAction", context.scene.frameworkReferences, 'audioFiles', translate=False,
                        icon='PLAY_AUDIO')
```

but I can't get it to work:

If the `obj.audioAction` property is a `StringProperty`

```
audioAction = StringProperty(name="Audio Effect", subtype='FILE_NAME')
```

i don't get anything to select from:

[image: no suggestions]

This makes sense, as the system has no way of knowing, that it should refer to the `fileName` StringProperty inside the `AudioFileNameGroup`.

If the `obj.audioAction` property is

```
audioAction = PointerProperty(type=AudioFileNameGroup, name="AudioAction")
```

it is not editable, and the ui is disabled:
[image: disabled ui]

How can I use `prop_search` on the `audioFiles` collectionproperty?

Comment: As a side note since you are looking at audio files, `bpy.path.extensions_audio` is a set of audio file extensions supported by the user's blender.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Set the name on the collection**

Set the name of the collection item, as this is what appears in the prop search. Simple test script, the collection is populated from a simple list.

```
import bpy

class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        obj = context.object        
        layout.prop_search(obj, "audioAction", context.scene, "audioFiles", icon='SPEAKER')


class AudioFileNameGroup(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    name = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="File Name", subtype='FILE_NAME')

def register():       
    bpy.utils.register_class(AudioFileNameGroup)
    audioAction = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Audio Effect", subtype='FILE_NAME')
    bpy.types.Object.audioAction = audioAction        
    bpy.types.Scene.audioFiles = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=AudioFileNameGroup)
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)

def unregister():
    # fill this in
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    items = (
        ('FOO', 'Foo', ''),
        ('BAR', 'Bar', '')
    )
    scene = bpy.context.scene
    for identifier, name, description in items:
        scene.audioFiles.add().name = name
```

Answer (score 1):

One more example with data-set of strips:

```
import bpy

class StripListPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Strip List Panel"
    bl_idname = "UI_PT_StripListPanel"
    bl_space_type = 'SEQUENCE_EDITOR'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'Strip Selector'

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.area.type == 'SEQUENCE_EDITOR'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        scene = context.scene
        ed = scene.sequence_editor

        layout.prop_search(scene, "selectedStrip", ed, "sequences", text="Selected Strip", icon='SEQ_STRIP_DUPLICATE')

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(StripListPanel)
    bpy.types.Scene.selectedStrip = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Selected Strip")

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(StripListPanel)

    del bpy.types.Scene.selectedStrip

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```