# template_search : How to properly use it with custom Collection Property?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

As I said in Title how [template_search](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html?highlight=uilayout#bpy.types.UILayout.template_search) and template_search_preview works?

Edit:

I want to use `template_search` to give search functionality.
Currently I'm using [`template_icon_view`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html?highlight=uilayout#bpy.types.UILayout.template_icon_view) with enum. It gives me nice popup where i can browse asset but with large enums it's not good UX.
[image]
So I want to implement Search functionality. [`template_ID_preview`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html?highlight=uilayout#bpy.types.UILayout.template_ID_preview)  can be used with only, well `IDs` not custom `PropertyGroup`

`prop_search` does work based on [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/110576/115433) example but it does not give thumbnail previews

I have this test code which gives me this result.
I can't select from drop-down.
And I get this error in console.

```
template_search_setup: pointer property not found: my_setting
```

[image].

```
import bpy

class SceneSettingItem(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    name: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Test Property", default="Unknown")
    value: bpy.props.IntProperty(name="Test Property", default=22)

bpy.utils.register_class(SceneSettingItem)

bpy.types.Scene.my_settings = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=SceneSettingItem)
bpy.types.Scene.my_setting = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=SceneSettingItem)

my_item = bpy.context.scene.my_settings.add()
my_item.name = "Spam"
my_item.value = 1000

my_item = bpy.context.scene.my_settings.add()
my_item.name = "Eggs"
my_item.value = 30

my_item = bpy.context.scene.my_settings.add()
my_item.name = "Foo"
my_item.value = 1000

class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        obj = context.object

        row = layout.row()
        row.template_search(context.scene,"my_setting",context.scene,"my_settings")
        
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(context.scene,"my_setting")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```