# Can a EnumProperty have dynamic name?

Tags: scripting, properties

I have defined a custom Enum property for the Material type:

```
bpy.types.Material.EMaterial = EnumProperty(
    items=[('none', 'None', ''), ('vertex_lit', 'Vertex Lit', ''), ('transparent', 'Transparent', ''), ('transparent_bfcall', 'Transparent Back Face Cull', '')], name="Material"
)
```

This’s how I display panel for each material of a selected object:

```
    def get_materials(self, object):
        slots = object.material_slots
        materials = []
        for slot in slots:
            if slot.material != None:
                materials.append(slot.material)
        return materials

    def draw_material(self, material):
        layout = self.layout
        column = layout.column()
        column.prop(material, 'EMaterial')

    def draw_materials(self, context):
        object = context.active_object
        materials = self.get_materials(object)
        for material in materials:
            self.draw_material(material)

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.object != None

    def draw(self, context):
        self.draw_materials(context)
```

[image]
**I want the name of the property (marked red in the image ) to be dynamic. i.e. it should depend on the material name itself.** For example if the name of the material is `material_1` the name of the property should be `material_1`. Is it possible to achieve it?

*P.S. please let me know if my question isn’t clear enough , I’ll elaborate it.*

Comment: You can also have a real preview of the materials by using an UIlist in 'Compact Mode': [Create an interface which is similar to the material list box?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/30446/31447)

Comment: Thank you for suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by adding the optional [`text`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.prop) argument to `column.prop(material, 'EMaterial')`.

```
column.prop(material, 'EMaterial', text=material.name)
```

[image]