# How to make custom list panel like "Vertex Groups" list

Tags: python, scripting, interface, add-on

Does anybody know how to create panel like this? (I am new to programming.)

Items of this list should have several data points `["name", value1, value2, ...]`

"+" button should add new item to list.

This is what I'm thinking:

- Let's call menu - "cList" & new item of this list - "nItem"
- value1 will be `def reName (bpy.context.object.name = "box")`
- value2 will be `scale z=0.5 - def zScale (bpy.context.object.scale[2] = 0.5)`

```
nItem = ["name", value1, value2, value3]
customList = []

customList.append (nItem) #add a new item to list
```

For new **nItem** list need to add button: "get/input name", "get/input Value1" etc.
or, when creating new item, it will be asking all parameters.

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30444/create-an-interface-which-is-similar-to-the-material-list-box