# Is there a way to display a multi-lines message in panel / popup?

Tags: python, scripting, panel

My add-on performs diverse measurements on an arbitrary number of selected objects. The measurements results are printed to the console and saved to drive as tabulated data and `.csv` files respectively. I'd like to also display them in the GUI in a pop-up window.

I have not found any way to display multi-lines messages in a panel and nothing in the API (v2.81) struck me as related.

I am currently going around by showing in the panel the 5 first and last measurements (*head()-like* and *tail()-like* previews).

Would anybody have an idea on how to display tabular data of arbitrary length in a panel?

Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT** (in response to @RayMairlot):

The message to be displayed has *n*-lines (each line being a set of measurements - fixed width - for one object). I can't know beforehand how many lines there will be (depends on the number of objects measured) and `row.label()` only display text on a single line (`\n` are not recognized). Thus, I am currently building my pop-up panel with a a fixed number of  `row.label()`statements (e.g. 10), that I populate with the  5 first and last lines of the message (measurements of the 5 first and last objects). I am not satisfied with this solution, it is just a workaround (better a preview of the results than no results displayed at all :-) ).

What I would need is either:

- a way to dynamically add `row = layout.row()` and `row.label(text)` statements to the panel to match the number of rows to display as it is invoked
- OR a way to display multilines messages (containing `\n`) in a single `row.label(text)`or equivalent.

I hope this clarifies.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you currently have to display the 5 first and last messages instead of all the data?

Comment: edited my original question to clarify this point.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159503/displaying-text-inside-an-addon-panel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example using an **UIList** based on the answer of [Create an interface which is similar to the material list box?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/30444/31447) and my modification for [Displaying text inside an addon Panel](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/159708/31447) to get some kind of *log window* as part of a popup. I've removed all superfluous operators and added a `CUSTOM_OT_popup` operator calling `invoke_props_dialog` in its `invoke` method as well as a `check` method for proper drawing:

[image]

```
# ##### BEGIN GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####
#
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
#  modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
#  as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
#  of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation,
#  Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA.
#
# ##### END GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####

bl_info = {
    "name": "log-uilist-dev",
    "description": "",
    "author": "p2or, brockmann",
    "version": (0, 1),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "Text Editor",
    "warning": "", # used for warning icon and text in addons panel
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "category": "Development"
}

import bpy

from bpy.props import (IntProperty,
                       BoolProperty,
                       StringProperty,
                       EnumProperty,
                       CollectionProperty)

from bpy.types import (Operator,
                       Panel,
                       PropertyGroup,
                       UIList)

# -------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Operators
# -------------------------------------------------------------------

class CUSTOM_OT_actions(Operator):
    """Move items up and down, add and remove"""
    bl_idname = "custom.list_action"
    bl_label = "List Actions"
    bl_description = "Move items up and down, add and remove"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}

    action: EnumProperty(
        items=(
            ('UP', "Up", ""),
            ('DOWN', "Down", ""),
            ('REMOVE', "Remove", ""),
            ('ADD', "Add", "")))

    list_item: StringProperty()

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        scn = context.scene
        idx = scn.custom_index

        try:
            item = scn.custom[idx]
        except IndexError:
            pass
        else:
            if self.action == 'DOWN' and idx < len(scn.custom) - 1:
                item_next = scn.custom[idx+1].name
                scn.custom.move(idx, idx+1)
                scn.custom_index += 1
                info = 'Item "%s" moved to position %d' % (item.name, scn.custom_index + 1)
                self.report({'INFO'}, info)

            elif self.action == 'UP' and idx >= 1:
                item_prev = scn.custom[idx-1].name
                scn.custom.move(idx, idx-1)
                scn.custom_index -= 1
                info = 'Item "%s" moved to position %d' % (item.name, scn.custom_index + 1)
                self.report({'INFO'}, info)

            elif self.action == 'REMOVE':
                info = 'Item "%s" removed from list' % (scn.custom[idx].name)
                scn.custom_index -= 1
                scn.custom.remove(idx)
                self.report({'INFO'}, info)

        if self.action == 'ADD':
            if self.list_item:
                item = scn.custom.add()
                item.name = self.list_item
                item.coll_id = len(scn.custom)
                scn.custom_index = len(scn.custom)-1
                info = '"%s" added to list' % (item.name)
                self.report({'INFO'}, info)

        return {"FINISHED"}


class CUSTOM_OT_clearList(Operator):
    """Clear all items of the list"""
    bl_idname = "custom.clear_list"
    bl_label = "Clear List"
    bl_description = "Clear all items of the list"
    bl_options = {'INTERNAL'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return bool(context.scene.custom)

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_confirm(self, event)

    def execute(self, context):
        if bool(context.scene.custom):
            context.scene.custom.clear()
            self.report({'INFO'}, "All items removed")
        else:
            self.report({'INFO'}, "Nothing to remove")
        return{'FINISHED'}


# -------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Drawing
# -------------------------------------------------------------------

class CUSTOM_UL_items(UIList):
    def draw_item(self, context, layout, data, item, icon, active_data, active_propname, index):
        split = layout.split(factor=0.2)
        split.label(text="%d" % (index))
        #split.prop(item, "name", text="", emboss=False, translate=False, icon=custom_icon)
        split.label(text=item.name) # avoids renaming the item by accident

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        pass   


class CUSTOM_OT_popup(Operator):
    bl_idname = "custom.call_popup"
    bl_label = "Log Window"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return True

    def execute(self, context):
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def check(self, context):
        return True

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self, width=500)

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scn = bpy.context.scene

        rows = 7
        row = layout.row()
        row.template_list("CUSTOM_UL_items", "", scn, "custom", scn, "custom_index", rows=rows)

        row = layout.row()
        add = row.operator(CUSTOM_OT_actions.bl_idname, icon="ADD", text="Add Log Line")
        add.list_item = "Error %d" % (len(scn.custom))
        add.action = 'ADD'

        row = layout.row().operator("custom.clear_list", icon="X")
        row = layout.row()


# -------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Collection
# -------------------------------------------------------------------

class CUSTOM_objectCollection(PropertyGroup):
    #name: StringProperty() -> Instantiated by default
    coll_type: StringProperty()
    coll_id: IntProperty()


# -------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Register & Unregister
# -------------------------------------------------------------------

classes = (
    CUSTOM_OT_actions,
    CUSTOM_OT_clearList,
    CUSTOM_UL_items,
    CUSTOM_objectCollection,
    CUSTOM_OT_popup
)

def register():
    from bpy.utils import register_class
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)

    # Custom scene properties
    bpy.types.Scene.custom = CollectionProperty(type=CUSTOM_objectCollection)
    bpy.types.Scene.custom_index = IntProperty()


def unregister():
    from bpy.utils import unregister_class
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        unregister_class(cls)

    del bpy.types.Scene.custom
    del bpy.types.Scene.custom_index


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

**Note:** the naming of the classes and variables might be off a little.