# How to build an operator that corrects StringProperty("subtype = 'DIR_PATH') from relative path?

Tags: python, path

I'm trying to build a "smart" operator, this has to transform a relative path (Cause of a lot of trouble sometimes for novice users), so I was thinking something like this, if the `StringProperty(subtype = 'DIR_PATH')` property is relative
I have written a script that demonstrates what I would like to do, but I don't know how to continue and if it is possible to do this.
As you understand (I hope) I try to build an operator which is passed the right argument to interact with it (In this case 2 distinct properties).

```
import bpy, os

bl_info = {
    "name": "Test",
    "author": "NoobCat",
    "version": (1, 0, 0),
    "blender": (2, 92, 0)
    }

class MYADDON_OT_Realpath(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Convert to Realpath"""
    bl_idname = "myaddon.realpath"
    bl_label = "Realpath"
    bl_options = {'INTERNAL'}
    
    path: bpy.props.StringProperty() # <-- Is useful?
      
    def execute(self,context):
        context.path # <-- Is Useful?
        os.path.realpath(bpy.path.abspath(context.path))# Im very confused 
        return{'FINISHED'}

class LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "Layout Demo"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        scn = context.scene
        preferences = bpy.context.preferences.addons[__name__].preferences
        scn_prop = scn.my_props
        
        layout = self.layout
        col = layout.column()
        #Case 1:
        col.prop(scn_prop, 'my_scene_path', text = "Add your scene prop path")
        if scn_prop.my_scene_path.startswith("//"):
            path = scn_prop.my_scene_path
            row = col.row()
            #row.context_pointer_set(name="path", data=path) <-- Is Useful?
            row.operator("myaddon.realpath", text = "Convert to realpath").path = path
        #Case 2:
        col.prop(preferences, 'my_preferences_path', text = "Add your preferences path")
        if preferences.my_preferences_path.startswith("//"):
            path = preferences.my_preferences_path
            row = col.row()
            #row.context_pointer_set(name="path", data=path) <-- Is Useful?
            row.operator("myaddon.realpath", text = "Convert to realpath").path = path

class MyAddonPreferences(bpy.types.AddonPreferences):    
    bl_idname = __name__
    my_preferences_path: bpy.props.StringProperty(subtype = 'DIR_PATH')

class SceneProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    my_scene_path: bpy.props.StringProperty(subtype = 'DIR_PATH')

classes = (MyAddonPreferences,
           SceneProperties,
           LayoutDemoPanel,
           MYADDON_OT_Realpath)

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)  
    bpy.types.Scene.my_props = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=SceneProperties)
def unregister():
    
    for cls in reversed(classes):       
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Don't, see: [How can I get the full path of the selected file from the file explorer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195938/how-can-i-get-the-full-path-of-the-selected-file-from-the-file-explorer/195971#195971)

Comment: Hello brockmann, yes i know :) The problem with that menu is that a lot of people struggle to find it, and even I sometimes find myself annoyed by that, but I don't want to change the blender options in this case, so I was thinking of a handy button that would do the dirty work in the immediate, with a message that warns, and under the button that resolves.
Then I am also intrigued as to how such an argument can be passed to the operator

Comment: Seriously? It is like it is. Take a minute and think about the concept and you'll see it's actually a great "feature". If that's so "annoying" to you consider to disable relative paths in the user prefs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOASe.png ... and yes your code is pretty bad. I'd suggest explain users how it actually works.

Comment: @brockmann agree a bit both ways here. It's my experience that setting the use relative paths in prefs and its value when using `bpy.ops.buttons.directory_browse` can sometimes be out of sync. Had looked at this re globbing from a file type string property without the need to write a file browser operator.  Added the method came up with re props. (usually via both in a propertygroup)

Comment: Still against this. There is usually more than one filepath to set and if there is one toggle in only one place to do that, the user even gets more confused, why there isn't such a toggle for all other paths... it's a design decision which has been made @batFINGER

Comment: No doubt. As mentioned sitting the fence a bit here. Method below could for example be used in conjunction with [your recent excellent :) answer to OP](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/220630/how-do-i-add-a-list-of-paths-in-the-blender-preferences-manually/220639#220639)  As is  changing 3 would require open filebrowser / open N window / (un)check use relative / accept, times 3 .  Or with bool prop in propgroup, click three checkoxes  (or perhaps  better still add another bool outside to toggle whole collection with one click)  btw perhaps link in first comment needs extra test

Comment: in case it is already, or set as  an abspath.  Another thing I find is for example setting filepaths (eg fonts etc, which is default "//"( in user prefs doesn't keep my choice of use relative, or use the global setting, find it can become a  bit _ad hoc_.

Comment: @batFINGER I don't deny that this *can* be useful somehow and I appreciate your answer as always. OP's decision... just a lot of code to maintain vs. a simple explanation about how paths in blender work, what "//" actually means and how to display the absolute path if required which is even more useful to the user IMHO. Good critics on the linked answer, should indeed add a test for abolute paths, although more like a general python thing, I'm going to edit the answer if I have the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**With a setter and getter.**

*Instead of writing an operator, here is a suggestion re using a boolean property to toggle between the two, and set the path accordingly.*

IIRC, (and I didn't) had asked a similar question re globbing string properties with a file or folder subtype, in particular to glob a file.  [Have asked a new question.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/220911/globbing-file-type-stringproperty)

For the case shown in question, consider adding your own "use relative" property

Have set up a generic setter / getter on path property, and on boolean property the getter simply looks at if the path starts with "//" it is relative, and toggle using the setter.  Will also use the option available in filebrowser of setting `relative_path` of the invoked and active in the file browser,  operator [`bpy.ops.buttons.directory_browse()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.91/bpy.ops.buttons.html#bpy.ops.buttons.directory_browse)

[image]
*Example, file saved in tmp folder, draw method added to text editor footer for testing*

```
import bpy

def update(self, context):
    print("update")
 
def set(self, value):
    print("setter") 
    self["foo"] = value
         
def get(self):
    return self.get("foo", "//")

bpy.types.Scene.foo = bpy.props.StringProperty(
    subtype='DIR_PATH',
    default="//", 
    get=get,
    set=set,
    update=update,
    )
    
def get(self):
    return self.foo.startswith("//")

def set(self, value):
    print("set relative", value)
    if value:
        self["foo"] = bpy.path.relpath(self.foo)
    else:
        self["foo"] = bpy.path.abspath(self.foo)    

bpy.types.Scene.foo_relative_path = bpy.props.BoolProperty(
    name="Use Relative",
    get=get,
    set=set,
    )


def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    row = layout.row(align=True)
    row.prop(context.scene, "foo")    
    row.prop(context.scene, "foo_relative_path")



classes = []


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.TEXT_HT_footer.append(draw)

def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    bpy.types.TEXT_HT_footer.remove(draw)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Sounds very interesting, just a little confusing in my head, why did you call get() set() functions the same way? There are functions there with the same name, is that right?

Comment: re same name, just lazy ... the property will use the last one defined _ie_ first prop uses first get, second prop uses second get.