# Globbing FILE_TYPE StringProperty

Tags: python, properties, file-browser

In a [recent question a user asks about setting relative / absolute paths from a `subtype='DIR_PATH'` string property](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/220881/how-to-build-an-operator-that-corrects-stringpropertysubtype-dir-path-fro).  Made me recall, (actually thought I had asked this, couldn't find)  re the ability to  glob a `subtype='FILE_PATH'` string property.

When the file / dir path  subtypes are set; to the layout is added a button to invoke the filebrowser.

```
layout.prop(ob, "file_path")
```

For the case of file path a button is added to open the filebrowser using [`bpy.ops.buttons.file_browse()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.91/bpy.ops.buttons.html#bpy.ops.buttons.file_browse) This operator has all the *"usual suspects"* of an operator that invokes the file browser.  (Akin to using `ImportHelper, ExportHelper`)

For example, if this was a regular operator in layout could

```
op = layout.operator("buttons.file_browse")
op.filter_python = True
op.use_relative = True.
```

to glob python files and make a relative path.

and AFAIK there is no way to

1. When using subtype laid out as a property access and change the browse buttons operator properties
2. Or not using subtype pass the string property name to the operator to re-use the operator eg

   row.prop(ob, "file_path") # without making it a file subtype
   op = row.operator("buttons.browse_file")

and have the result populate the property.

Was hoping to "unlock" somehow using button context as shown here adding an [operator to the context menu (right click).](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Menu.html?highlight=button_operator#extending-the-button-context-menu), by setting a context pointer to "button_prop", but alas found myself going in circles. *Or using a hack like a depsgraph update handler or a callback on FILEBROWSER space to set the operator props if it active, kinda emulating somewhat  the `check` method in an ExportHelper operator*

To paraphrase, is there a way to use the string property subtype `FILE_PATH` and glob the filebrowser invoked via the UI generated button?