# How to select and automatically assign a material item of a custom UIlist?

Tags: python, materials, scripting, interface

I'm really struggling finding info or anything about this.

I've made a an UI list with an imported list of material and displayed on the 3d view ui panel. So far a button 'set material' is changing the material on active object and it works fine.

But I would like to remove this button and directly change the material when I press on an item in the list.

[image: material uilist]

Comment: Is your code copied from: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30444/create-an-interface-which-is-similar-to-the-material-list-box/30446#30446 ?

Comment: Yes it is, it matched perfectly my needs at a certain point. The mat list is imported from a server (that's why the load Material list is unable).

Comment: I got PTSD from when I tried to work with UIlists previously but as i recall, you can link the active index to an `IntProperty` and use the `update` callback to know when an element is clicked

Comment: @Gorgious worked perfectly ! Thank you