# 'Search Bar' for custom UI Lists - prop_search

Tags: python, scripting, interface, properties

I'm trying to create the ability to have multiple UI Lists (custom, assigned to `bpy.types.Object`) which can be selected and have their names edited by use of a `'prop_search'` widget.

[image]

In this example picture, there's a UI List of Particle Effects, and beneath it a property_search to change the particle effect being edited.

What I'm looking for is the opposite. A property_search tab which changes the active 'list' being worked on. With multiple 'instances' of the UI List existing in the project.

How might this be achieved?

Comment: does [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/249940/42221) answer your question?

Comment: @MartyFouts Sorry for the long wait, got around to this at last.  No, I don't think it answers the question. I'm trying to use a `template_ID` to select a Collection Property.

Comment: @MartyFouts I re created the question, I think it's clearer what I'm asking https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/263159/search-box-for-custom-collectionproperty