# Search Box for Custom CollectionProperty

Tags: python, scripting, interface, data-blocks

When you have 'particle effects', or 'sounds' or 'actions' (among others), there's a dropdown like this:

[image]

It lists all items of a data type, and allows you to create a new one, change the active one, or have multiple objects share the same one. So that, for example, multiple objects can have share the same particle system 'settings'.

[image]

How can I create this with a custom CollectionProperty (pointing to a PropertyGroup)?

---

In python it's called a `template_ID`. The `prop_search` widget can also work, but `template_id` is preferable. It's formatted:

```
col.prop_search(item, 'name', scene, 'objects')
```

Where `item, 'name'` is the property that will be saved to, and `scene, 'objects'` is where the list of options comes from.

This is how the UI is formatted, but my problem is how is the data formatted?

The 'list of options' part expects a PointerProperty and not a CollectionProperty. And what data type should I use in the the property that will be saved to, to set the object's active Collection?

Comment: Hello ! It looks like you answered your own question, which is awesome. But on this site you should use the form at the bottom of the page to add your answer. It will tell every other user that this question has been answered and helps with archiving it for later use. Cheers

Comment: @Gorgious It's not answered, I've added clarification.