# Create a list to add Objects and Materials

Tags: python, panel

I want to create a panel list where I can add Objects and Materials. The purpose of this list is to bake the actions of the selected objects and materials to be able to export them to glTF.

I already have the code to bake them, but I don´t have the UI to select which objects and material should be baked.

I have tried to understand the examples in Blender documentation, but to be honest, I now feel I understand even less :-s

Could someone provide a small example on how to create such a panel?

Comment: Hello ! You have some examples in the text editor > Templates > Python > UI Panel

Comment: [Create an interface which is similar to the material list box](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30444/create-an-interface-which-is-similar-to-the-material-list-box)

Answer (score 0):

As Gorgious commented, this is the code:

```
import bpy


class MATERIAL_UL_matslots_example(bpy.types.UIList):
    # The draw_item function is called for each item of the collection that is visible in the list.
    #   data is the RNA object containing the collection,
    #   item is the current drawn item of the collection,
    #   icon is the "computed" icon for the item (as an integer, because some objects like materials or textures
    #   have custom icons ID, which are not available as enum items).
    #   active_data is the RNA object containing the active property for the collection (i.e. integer pointing to the
    #   active item of the collection).
    #   active_propname is the name of the active property (use 'getattr(active_data, active_propname)').
    #   index is index of the current item in the collection.
    #   flt_flag is the result of the filtering process for this item.
    #   Note: as index and flt_flag are optional arguments, you do not have to use/declare them here if you don't
    #         need them.
    def draw_item(self, context, layout, data, item, icon, active_data, active_propname):
        ob = data
        slot = item
        ma = slot.material
        # draw_item must handle the three layout types... Usually 'DEFAULT' and 'COMPACT' can share the same code.
        if self.layout_type in {'DEFAULT', 'COMPACT'}:
            # You should always start your row layout by a label (icon + text), or a non-embossed text field,
            # this will also make the row easily selectable in the list! The later also enables ctrl-click rename.
            # We use icon_value of label, as our given icon is an integer value, not an enum ID.
            # Note "data" names should never be translated!
            if ma:
                layout.prop(ma, "name", text="", emboss=False, icon_value=icon)
            else:
                layout.label(text="", translate=False, icon_value=icon)
        # 'GRID' layout type should be as compact as possible (typically a single icon!).
        elif self.layout_type in {'GRID'}:
            layout.alignment = 'CENTER'
            layout.label(text="", icon_value=icon)


# And now we can use this list everywhere in Blender. Here is a small example panel.
class UIListPanelExample(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "UIList Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_ui_list_example"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        obj = context.object

        # template_list now takes two new args.
        # The first one is the identifier of the registered UIList to use (if you want only the default list,
        # with no custom draw code, use "UI_UL_list").
        layout.template_list("MATERIAL_UL_matslots_example", "", obj, "material_slots", obj, "active_material_index")

        # The second one can usually be left as an empty string.
        # It's an additional ID used to distinguish lists in case you
        # use the same list several times in a given area.
        layout.template_list("MATERIAL_UL_matslots_example", "compact", obj, "material_slots",
                             obj, "active_material_index", type='COMPACT')


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MATERIAL_UL_matslots_example)
    bpy.utils.register_class(UIListPanelExample)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MATERIAL_UL_matslots_example)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(UIListPanelExample)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

If you run it in the text editor, you can see the list here:

[image]

You can easily "get" the code by tapping "new" in the text editor and then:

[image]

With the "UI Panel Simple" you can add objects.

[image]

Comment: Well, this is the documentation I tried to understand but I had difficulties to