# Create A tree of string properties

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I want to approach a script to make a tree of string list- like this ,(kind of advance version of Vertex group template list)  [image]

I can make a template list tho for start, but don't know how to make subnode to that and attach to it.

```
    bl_info = {
        "name": "object-uilist-dev",
        "description": "",
        "author": "p2or",
        "version": (0, 1),
        "blender": (2, 80, 0),
        "location": "Text Editor",
        "warning": "", # used for warning icon and text in addons panel
        "wiki_url": "",
        "tracker_url": "",
        "category": "Development"
    }

    import bpy

    from bpy.props import (IntProperty,
                           BoolProperty,
                           StringProperty,
                           CollectionProperty)

    from bpy.types import (Operator,
                           Panel,
                           PropertyGroup,
                           UIList)

    # -------------------------------------------------------------------
    #   Operators
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------

    class CUSTOM_OT_actions(Operator):
        """Move items up and down, add and remove"""
        bl_idname = "custom.list_action"
        bl_label = "List Actions"
        bl_description = "Move items up and down, add and remove"
        bl_options = {'REGISTER'}

        action: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
            items=(
                ('UP', "Up", ""),
                ('DOWN', "Down", ""),
                ('REMOVE', "Remove", ""),
                ('ADD', "Add", "")))

        def invoke(self, context, event):
            scn = context.scene
            idx = scn.custom_index

            try:
                item = scn.custom[idx]
            except IndexError:
                pass
            else:
                if self.action == 'DOWN' and idx < len(scn.custom) - 1:
                    item_next = scn.custom[idx+1].name
                    scn.custom.move(idx, idx+1)
                    scn.custom_index += 1
                    info = 'Item "%s" moved to position %d' % (item.name, scn.custom_index + 1)
                    self.report({'INFO'}, info)

                elif self.action == 'UP' and idx >= 1:
                    item_prev = scn.custom[idx-1].name
                    scn.custom.move(idx, idx-1)
                    scn.custom_index -= 1
                    info = 'Item "%s" moved to position %d' % (item.name, scn.custom_index + 1)
                    self.report({'INFO'}, info)

                elif self.action == 'REMOVE':
                    info = 'Item "%s" removed from list' % (scn.custom[idx].name)
                    scn.custom_index -= 1
                    scn.custom.remove(idx)
                    self.report({'INFO'}, info)

            if self.action == 'ADD':
                item = scn.custom.add()
                item.name = "Your Name"
                item.id = len(scn.custom)
                scn.custom_index = len(scn.custom)-1
                info = '"%s" added to list' % (item.name)
                self.report({'INFO'}, info)
            return {"FINISHED"}


    class CUSTOM_OT_printItems(Operator):
        """Print all items and their properties to the console"""
        bl_idname = "custom.print_items"
        bl_label = "Print Items to Console"
        bl_description = "Print all items and their properties to the console"
        bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

        reverse_order: BoolProperty(
            default=False,
            name="Reverse Order")

        @classmethod
        def poll(cls, context):
            return bool(context.scene.custom)

        def execute(self, context):
            scn = context.scene
            if self.reverse_order:
                for i in range(scn.custom_index, -1, -1):        
                    item = scn.custom[i]
                    print ("Name:", item.name,"-", "ID:", item.id )
            else:
                for item in scn.custom:
                    print ("Name:", item.name,"-", "ID", item.id)
            return{'FINISHED'}


    class CUSTOM_OT_clearList(Operator):
        """Clear all items of the list"""
        bl_idname = "custom.clear_list"
        bl_label = "Clear List"
        bl_description = "Clear all items of the list"
        bl_options = {'INTERNAL'}

        @classmethod
        def poll(cls, context):
            return bool(context.scene.custom)

        def invoke(self, context, event):
            return context.window_manager.invoke_confirm(self, event)

        def execute(self, context):
            if bool(context.scene.custom):
                context.scene.custom.clear()
                self.report({'INFO'}, "All items removed")
            else:
                self.report({'INFO'}, "Nothing to remove")
            return{'FINISHED'}


    # -------------------------------------------------------------------
    #   Drawing
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------

    class CUSTOM_UL_items(UIList):
        def draw_item(self, context, layout, data, item, icon, active_data, active_propname, index):
            split = layout.split(factor=0.3)
            split.label(text="Index: %d" % (index))
            custom_icon = "COLOR"
            split.prop(item, "name", icon=custom_icon, emboss=False, text="")

        def invoke(self, context, event):
            pass   

    class CUSTOM_PT_objectList(Panel):
        """Adds a custom panel to the TEXT_EDITOR"""
        bl_idname = 'TEXT_PT_my_panel'
        bl_space_type = "TEXT_EDITOR"
        bl_region_type = "UI"
        bl_label = "Custom Object List Demo"

        def draw(self, context):
            layout = self.layout
            scn = bpy.context.scene

            rows = 2
            row = layout.row()
            row.template_list("CUSTOM_UL_items", "", scn, "custom", scn, "custom_index", rows=rows)

            col = row.column(align=True)
            col.operator("custom.list_action", icon='ZOOM_IN', text="").action = 'ADD'
            col.operator("custom.list_action", icon='ZOOM_OUT', text="").action = 'REMOVE'
            col.separator()
            col.operator("custom.list_action", icon='TRIA_UP', text="").action = 'UP'
            col.operator("custom.list_action", icon='TRIA_DOWN', text="").action = 'DOWN'

            row = layout.row()
            col = row.column(align=True)
            row = col.row(align=True)
            row.operator("custom.print_items", icon="LINENUMBERS_ON") #LINENUMBERS_OFF, ANIM
            row = col.row(align=True)
            row.operator("custom.clear_list", icon="X")


    # -------------------------------------------------------------------
    #   Collection
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------

    class CUSTOM_colorCollection(PropertyGroup):
        #name: StringProperty() -> Instantiated by default
        id: IntProperty()

    # -------------------------------------------------------------------
    #   Register & Unregister
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------

    classes = (
        CUSTOM_OT_actions,
        CUSTOM_OT_printItems,
        CUSTOM_OT_clearList,
        CUSTOM_UL_items,
        CUSTOM_PT_objectList,
        CUSTOM_colorCollection,
    )

    def register():
        from bpy.utils import register_class
        for cls in classes:
            register_class(cls)

        # Custom scene properties
        bpy.types.Scene.custom = CollectionProperty(type=CUSTOM_colorCollection)
        bpy.types.Scene.custom_index = IntProperty()


    def unregister():
        from bpy.utils import unregister_class
        for cls in reversed(classes):
            unregister_class(cls)

        del bpy.types.Scene.custom
        del bpy.types.Scene.custom_index


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        register()
```

There is a post about approaching tree of property on Blender artist, but that code doesn't work :/
https://blenderartists.org/t/blender-treelist-expanding-subelements-ui/1191260

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in [my previous answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249953/create-custom-ui-list-with-string-objects-and-store-them-to-addon-itself/249968#249968), `name` is instantiated by default. Notice that the coding style/quality of the [example given](https://blenderartists.org/t/blender-treelist-expanding-subelements-ui/) is not particularly beautiful, try to revise the code under consideration of [Create an interface which is similar to the material list box](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30444/create-an-interface-which-is-similar-to-the-material-list-box/30446#30446).

[image]

```
import bpy

from bpy.types import PropertyGroup

from bpy.props import (
    CollectionProperty,
    IntProperty,
    BoolProperty,
    StringProperty,
    PointerProperty,
)



#
# This is what I am using to hold a single tree node in my raw example data.
# The entire example data is stored in **bpy.context.scene.myNodes**
#
class MyListTreeNode(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    selfIndex : bpy.props.IntProperty(default=-1)
    parentIndex : bpy.props.IntProperty(default=-1)
    childCount : bpy.props.IntProperty(default=0)


#
#   This represents an item that in the collection being rendered by
#   props.template_list. This collection is stored in ______
#   The collection represents a currently visible subset of MyListTreeNode
#   plus some extra info to render in a treelike fashion, eg indent.
#
class MyListTreeItem(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    indent: bpy.props.IntProperty(default=0)
    expanded: bpy.props.BoolProperty(default=False)
    nodeIndex : bpy.props.IntProperty(default=-1) #index into the real tree data.
    childCount: bpy.props.IntProperty(default=0) #should equal myNodes[nodeIndex].childCount
    
  


def SetupNodeData():
    bpy.types.Scene.myNodes = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=MyListTreeNode)
    myNodes = bpy.context.scene.myNodes
    myNodes.clear()
    
    for i in range(5):
        node = myNodes.add()
        node.name = "node {}".format(i)
        node.selfIndex = len(myNodes)-1
        
    for i in range(4):
        node = myNodes.add()
        node.name = "subnode {}".format(i)
        node.selfIndex = len(myNodes)-1
        node.parentIndex = 2

    parentIndex = len(myNodes)-2
        
    for i in range(2):
        node = myNodes.add()
        node.name = "subnode {}".format(i)
        node.selfIndex = len(myNodes)-1
        node.parentIndex = parentIndex
        
    parentIndex = len(myNodes)-3
        
    for i in range(2):
        node = myNodes.add()
        node.name = "subnode {}".format(i)
        node.selfIndex = len(myNodes)-1
        node.parentIndex = parentIndex
        
    parentIndex = len(myNodes)-1
        
    for i in range(2):
        node = myNodes.add()
        node.name = "subnode {}".format(i)
        node.selfIndex = len(myNodes)-1
        node.parentIndex = parentIndex
        
    # calculate childCount for all nodes
    for  node in myNodes :
        if node.parentIndex != -1:
            parent = myNodes[node.parentIndex]
            parent.childCount = parent.childCount + 1
            
    print("++++ SetupNodeData ++++")
    print("Node count: {}".format(len(myNodes)))
    for i in range(len(myNodes)):
        node = myNodes[i]
        print("{} node:{} child:{}".format(i, node.name, node.childCount))
        
        

def NewListItem( treeList, node):
    item = treeList.add()
    item.name = node.name
    item.nodeIndex = node.selfIndex
    item.childCount = node.childCount
    return item


def SetupListFromNodeData():
    bpy.types.Scene.myListTree = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=MyListTreeItem)
    bpy.types.Scene.myListTree_index = IntProperty()
    
    treeList = bpy.context.scene.myListTree
    treeList.clear()
    
    myNodes = bpy.context.scene.myNodes
    
    for node in myNodes:
        #print("node name:{} parent:{} kids:{}".format(node.name, node.parentIndex, node.children))
        if -1 == node.parentIndex :
            NewListItem(treeList, node)

#
#   Inserts a new item into myListTree at position item_index
#   by copying data from node
#
def InsertBeneath( treeList, parentIndex, parentIndent, node):
    after_index =parentIndex + 1
    item = NewListItem(treeList,node)
    item.indent = parentIndent+1
    item_index = len(treeList) -1 #because add() appends to end.
    treeList.move(item_index,after_index)


def IsChild( child_node_index, parent_node_index, node_list):
    if child_node_index == -1:
        print("bad node index")
        return False
    
    child = node_list[child_node_index]
    if child.parentIndex == parent_node_index:
        return True
    return False



#
#   Operation to Expand a list item.
#
class MyListTreeItem_Expand(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.mylisttree_expand" #NOT SURE WHAT TO PUT HERE.
    bl_label = "Tool Name"
    
    button_id: IntProperty(default=0)

    def execute(self, context):
        item_index = self.button_id
        item_list = context.scene.myListTree
        item = item_list[item_index]
        item_indent = item.indent
        
        nodeIndex = item.nodeIndex
        
        myNodes = context.scene.myNodes
        
        print(item)
        if item.expanded:
            print("=== Collapse Item {} ===".format(item_index))
            item.expanded = False
            
            nextIndex = item_index+1
            while True:
                if nextIndex >= len(item_list):
                    break
                if item_list[nextIndex].indent <= item_indent:
                    break
                item_list.remove(nextIndex)
        else:
            print("=== Expand Item {} ===".format(item_index))
            item.expanded = True
            
            for n in myNodes:
                if nodeIndex == n.parentIndex:
                    InsertBeneath(item_list, item_index, item_indent, n)
            
        return {'FINISHED'}
    

#
#   Several debug operations
#   (bundled into a single operator with an "action" property)
#
class MyListTreeItem_Debug(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.mylisttree_debug"
    bl_label = "Debug"
    
    action: StringProperty(default="default")
    
    def execute(self, context):
        action = self.action
        if "print" == action:
            print("=== Debug Print ====")
        elif "reset3" == action:
            print("=== Debug Reset ====")
            SetupListFromNodeData()
        elif "clear" == action:
            print("=== Debug Clear ====")
            bpy.context.scene.myListTree.clear()
        else:
            print("unknown debug action: "+action)

        return {'FINISHED'}


#
#   My List UI class to draw my MyListTreeItem
#   (The most important thing it does is show how to draw a list item)
#
#note this naming convention is important. For more info search for _UL_ in:
# https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Addons
class MYLISTTREEITEM_UL_basic(bpy.types.UIList):

    def draw_item(self, context, layout, data, item, icon, active_data, active_propname, index):
        scene = data
        #print(data, item, active_data, active_propname)
        if self.layout_type in {'DEFAULT', 'COMPACT'}:
            
            for i in range(item.indent):
                split = layout.split(factor = 0.1)
            
            col = layout.column()
            
            #print("item:{} childCount:{}".format(item.name, item.childCount)) 
            if item.childCount == 0:
               op = col.operator("object.mylisttree_expand", text="", icon='DOT')
               op.button_id = index
               col.enabled = False
            #if False:
            #    pass
            elif item.expanded :
                op = col.operator("object.mylisttree_expand", text="", icon='TRIA_DOWN')
                op.button_id = index
            else:
                op = col.operator("object.mylisttree_expand", text="", icon='TRIA_RIGHT')
                op.button_id = index
            
            col = layout.column()
            col.label(text=item.name)
            

#
#   My Panel UI, assigned to view.
#
class SCENE_PT_mylisttree(bpy.types.Panel):

    bl_label = "My List Tree"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_materials"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "My Category"

    def draw(self, context):

        scn = context.scene
        layout = self.layout
        
        row = layout.row()
        row.template_list(
            "MYLISTTREEITEM_UL_basic",
            "",
            scn,
            "myListTree",
            scn,
            "myListTree_index",
            sort_lock = True
            )
            
        grid = layout.grid_flow( columns = 2 )
        
        grid.operator("object.mylisttree_debug", text="Reset").action = "reset3"
        grid.operator("object.mylisttree_debug", text="Clear").action = "clear"
        grid.operator("object.mylisttree_debug", text="Print").action = "print"


classes = (
        MyListTreeNode,
        MyListTreeItem,
        MyListTreeItem_Expand,
        MyListTreeItem_Debug,
        MYLISTTREEITEM_UL_basic,
        SCENE_PT_mylisttree)


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)

    SetupNodeData()
    SetupListFromNodeData()


def unregister():
    # fill this in.
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```