# How to use Property Definitions and PropertyGroups with UILists?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, add-on, properties

Ok I have to be honest here, UIList are confusing and I haven't been able to find any good documentation to help me with this question:

How do I go about using IntProperty, BoolProperty, StringProperty, CollectionProperty, EnumProperty, properly with a UIList? I want to be able to pass those properties to other Operators and functions.

**What I have tried:**

The furthest I was able to get is the following:

```
class CUSTOM_UL_items(UIList):

    def draw_item(self, context, layout, data, item, icon, active_data, active_propname, index):
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool
        obj = item.obj
        custom_icon = "OUTLINER_OB_%s" % obj.type
        split = layout.split(factor=0.3)
        split.label(text=f' {index}')

        split.prop(mytool, "item1")  # StringProperty from __init__.py
        split.prop(mytool, "ruleEnum")  # EnumProperty from __init__.py
        split.prop(mytool, "item2")  # StringProperty from __init__.py

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        pass
```

Where `item1, ruleEnum, and item2` are defined in a PropertyGroup class:

```
# User input Property Group:
class BMNFTS_PGT_MyProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):

    # Rules for Logic:
    logicBool: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Logic")
    item1: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="item1")
    ruleEnum: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name="",
        description="Select DNA Rule",
        items=[
            ('Only with', "Only with", "Only with Rule"),
            ('Never with', "Never with", "Never with Rule")
        ]
    )
    item2: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="item2")
```

Here is a git repo I created for this question, it's completely self contained so you can easily set it up in Blender with just the zipped **init**.py file: https://github.com/torrinworx/Blender_UList/blob/main/__init__.py

The panel is located in the 3D View after you install it to Blender, press the 'N' key when in the 3D viewport to open the side view. The panel name is `Blender_UIList`.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

In the above UIList there are two StringProperty and one EnumProperty with two values in the drop down. There are multiple issues with this setup:

1. I cannot call these individually by the UIList index and use them in an `execute` function Operator. (or at least I don't know how)
2. Each Index shows the same values for each Property, if you change `item1` index 0 to 5 for example, `item1` index 1 and 2 would be set to 5. So each element in the UIList isn't 'independent'.

**Resources I've found/used:**

And yes, I have checked out the following links:

- [Create an interface which is similar to the material list box](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30444/create-an-interface-which-is-similar-to-the-material-list-box)
- [How to create a custom UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57306/how-to-create-a-custom-ui)
- https://sinestesia.co/blog/tutorials/amazing-uilists-in-blender/

I did find this repo that looks like it has possibly an IntProperty within a UIList: https://github.com/p2or/blender-loom

Here is his example:

[image]

I can't really say I understand what it does, but it seems to be what I'm looking for. However main file has almost 5000 lines of code and I wouldn't even know where to start.

**Summary of questions**

How do I create a UIList where each item in the list contains it's own independent Property (StringProperty, IntProperty, EnumProperty, etc.)?

How do I call the Properties in that UIList? For example, pass them to an `execute` function with an Operator?

I can't tell if it's a logic thing that I'm struggling to understand with the UIList, or just some Blender UI method in general I'm completely unaware of. Anyhow, I really appreciate the communities help on this one, thank you for your time!

Torrin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have created an example add-on at this GitHub repo: https://github.com/torrinworx/Blender_UList

Here is the code:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Blender_UIList",
    "author": "Torrin Leonard",
    "version": (1, 0, 0),
    "blender": (3, 0, 0),
    "location": "View3D",
    "description": "Example of UIList with Property functionality.",
    "category": "Development",
}

import bpy
from bpy.props import (IntProperty,
                       BoolProperty,
                       StringProperty,
                       CollectionProperty,
                       PointerProperty)

from bpy.types import (Operator,
                       Panel,
                       PropertyGroup,
                       UIList)

# User input Property Group:
class rules_PGT(PropertyGroup):

    # Rules for Logic:
    logicBool: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Logic")
    item1: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="item1")
    ruleEnum: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name="",
        description="Select DNA Rule",
        items=[
            ('Only with', "Only with", "Only with Rule"),
            ('Never with', "Never with", "Never with Rule")
        ]
    )
    item2: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="item2")

# -------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Operators
# -------------------------------------------------------------------

class CUSTOM_OT_actions(Operator):
    """Move items up and down, add and remove"""
    bl_idname = "rule_list.list_action"
    bl_label = "List Actions"
    bl_description = "Move items up and down, add and remove"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}

    action: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        items=(
            ('UP', "Up", ""),
            ('DOWN', "Down", ""),
            ('REMOVE', "Remove", ""),
            ('ADD', "Add", "")))

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        scn = context.scene
        idx = scn.rule_list_index

        try:
            item = scn.rule_list[idx]
        except IndexError:
            pass
        else:
            if self.action == 'DOWN' and idx < len(scn.rule_list) - 1:
                item_next = scn.rule_list[idx + 1].name
                scn.rule_list.move(idx, idx + 1)
                scn.rule_list_index += 1
                info = 'Item "%s" moved to position %d' % (item.name, scn.rule_list_index + 1)
                self.report({'INFO'}, info)

            elif self.action == 'UP' and idx >= 1:
                item_prev = scn.rule_list[idx - 1].name
                scn.rule_list.move(idx, idx - 1)
                scn.rule_list_index -= 1
                info = 'Item "%s" moved to position %d' % (item.name, scn.rule_list_index + 1)
                self.report({'INFO'}, info)

            elif self.action == 'REMOVE':
                info = 'Item "%s" removed from list' % (scn.rule_list[idx].name)
                scn.rule_list_index -= 1
                scn.rule_list.remove(idx)
                self.report({'INFO'}, info)

        if self.action == 'ADD':
            item = scn.rule_list.add()
            item.name = f"Rule {idx +1}"

            scn.rule_list_index = len(scn.rule_list) - 1
            info = '"%s" added to list' % (item.name)
            self.report({'INFO'}, info)

        return {"FINISHED"}

class CUSTOM_OT_printItems(Operator):
    """Print all items and their properties to the console"""
    bl_idname = "rule_list.print_items"
    bl_label = "Print Items to Console"
    bl_description = "Print all items and their properties to the console"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    reverse_order: BoolProperty(
        default=False,
        name="Reverse Order")

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return bool(context.scene.rule_list)

    def execute(self, context):
        scn = context.scene
        if self.reverse_order:
            for i in range(scn.rule_list_index, -1, -1):
                ob = scn.rule_list[i].obj
                print("Object:", ob, "-", ob.name, ob.type)
        else:
            for item in scn.rule_list:
                ob = item.obj
                print("Object:", ob, "-", ob.name, ob.type)
        return {'FINISHED'}

class CUSTOM_OT_clearList(Operator):
    """Clear all items of the list"""
    bl_idname = "rule_list.clear_list"
    bl_label = "Clear List"
    bl_description = "Clear all items of the list"
    bl_options = {'INTERNAL'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return bool(context.scene.rule_list)

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_confirm(self, event)

    def execute(self, context):
        if bool(context.scene.rule_list):
            context.scene.rule_list.clear()
            self.report({'INFO'}, "All items removed")
        else:
            self.report({'INFO'}, "Nothing to remove")
        return {'FINISHED'}

# -------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Drawing
# -------------------------------------------------------------------

class RULES_UIList(UIList):
    def draw_item(self, context, layout, data, item, icon, active_data, active_propname, index):
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool

        split = layout.split(factor=0.3)
        split.label(text=f'{index}')

        split.prop(mytool, "item1")
        # split.prop(item, data, "item1", text="", emboss=False, translate=False, )


    def invoke(self, context, event):
        pass

class CUSTOM_PT_objectList(Panel):
    """Adds a custom panel to the TEXT_EDITOR"""
    bl_label = "UIList Test"
    bl_idname = "uilisttest_PT_uilisttest"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'Blender_UIList'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool

        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(mytool, "logicBool")

        rows = 2
        row = layout.row()
        row.template_list("RULES_UIList", "The_List", scene, "rule_list", scene, "rule_list_index", rows=rows)

        col = row.column(align=True)
        col.operator("rule_list.list_action", icon='ADD', text="").action = 'ADD'
        col.operator("rule_list.list_action", icon='REMOVE', text="").action = 'REMOVE'
        col.separator()
        col.operator("rule_list.list_action", icon='TRIA_UP', text="").action = 'UP'
        col.operator("rule_list.list_action", icon='TRIA_DOWN', text="").action = 'DOWN'

        row = layout.row()
        col = row.column(align=True)
        row = col.row(align=True)
        row.operator("rule_list.print_items", icon="LINENUMBERS_ON")
        row = col.row(align=True)
        row.operator("rule_list.clear_list", icon="X")

# -------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Collection
# -------------------------------------------------------------------

class CUSTOM_PG_objectCollection(PropertyGroup):
    # name: StringProperty() -> Instantiated by default
    obj: PointerProperty(
        name="Object",
        type=bpy.types.Object)


# Register and Unregister classes from Blender:
classes = (
    CUSTOM_OT_actions,
    CUSTOM_OT_clearList,
    CUSTOM_OT_printItems,
    RULES_UIList,
    rules_PGT,
    CUSTOM_PT_objectList,
    CUSTOM_PG_objectCollection,
)

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)

    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=rules_PGT)

    # UIList:
    bpy.types.Scene.rule_list = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=rules_PGT)
    bpy.types.Scene.rule_list_index = bpy.props.IntProperty(name="Rule list index.", default=100)

def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)

    del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool

    # UIList:
    del bpy.types.Scene.rule_list
    del bpy.types.Scene.rule_list_index


if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```