# How to change values in UIList if a list from StringProperty is used as data

Tags: scripting, add-on

I want to be able to change the names of items directly in the list (using double-clicking). But at the moment, the list cannot be edited. Maybe I forgot to put the right attribute somewhere, or am I using the wrong logic? Tell me please.

Script

```
import bpy, sys, os
from bpy.props import EnumProperty, StringProperty, IntProperty, CollectionProperty, PointerProperty, BoolProperty
from bpy.types import PropertyGroup, UIList, Operator, Panel
from dataclasses import dataclass

data_for_enum_presets = []
presets_list=[]
dir_path = 'E:\\'
pres_name = "scout"
last_action = ''

class BONES_PG_ListBones(PropertyGroup):
    bone: StringProperty(
        name="Name",
        description="A name bone",
        default="Bone")

class BONES_ListBones(UIList):
    def draw_item(self, context, layout, data, item, icon, acive_data, active_propname, index):
        custom_icon = 'BONE_DATA'
        bone = item.name

        if self.layout_type in {'DEFAULT', 'COMPACT'}:
            layout.label(text=item.name, icon=custom_icon)
            #layout.prop(bone, "name", text="", emboss=False)
        elif self.layout_type in {'GRID'}:
            layout.alignment = 'CENTER'
            layout.label(text="", icon=custom_icon)
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        print(bpy.context.scene.list_bones_id)
        pass

class BONES_ReloadPresets(Operator):
    bl_label = "Reload preset"
    bl_idname = "bones.reload_preset"
    bl_description = "Update information in presets."

    def execute(self, context):
        bones_reload_presets(self, context)
        return {'FINISHED'}

def enum_presets_list(self, context):
    enum_presets = []
    count = 0
    for obj in data_for_enum_presets:
        identifier = str(obj)
        name = str(obj)
        description = str(obj)
        number = count
        enum_presets.append((identifier, name, description, number))
        count += 1
    return enum_presets

def update_enum_presets_list(self, context):
    enum_list_presets_clearAllBones(self, context)
    if bpy.context.scene.list_presets.presets == 'Scout':
        enum_list_presets_showBone(self, context, 0)
    elif bpy.context.scene.list_presets.presets == 'Heavy':
        enum_list_presets_showBone(self, context, 1)
    elif bpy.context.scene.list_presets.presets == 'Heavy_duty':
        enum_list_presets_showBone(self, context, 2)
    elif bpy.context.scene.list_presets.presets == 'Highway':
        enum_list_presets_showBone(self, context, 3)
    elif bpy.context.scene.list_presets.presets == 'Offroad':
        enum_list_presets_showBone(self, context, 4)
    return None

def bones_reload_presets(self, context):
    preset=[]
    preset.clear()
    presets_list.clear()
    data_for_enum_presets.clear()
    
    bones_load_presets()
    
    update_enum_presets_list(self, context)
    return{'FINISHED'} 

class ListPresets(PropertyGroup):
    presets: EnumProperty(
        name= "Preset",
        description= "",
        items= enum_presets_list,
        update= update_enum_presets_list
    )
    
def bones_load_presets():
    preset=[]
    tmp=[]
    counter=0

    f=open(dir_path+'scout.txt','r')
    data_for_enum_presets.append('Scout')
    preset=f.readlines()
    preset=preset[::2]
    f.close()
    presets_list.append(preset)
    
    return{'FINISHED'}   

def enum_list_presets_showBone(self, context, preset_num):
    for i in range(len(presets_list[preset_num])):
        context.scene.list_bones.add()
        context.scene.list_bones[i]
        context.scene.list_bones[i].name = presets_list[preset_num][i]
        context.scene.list_bones[i].name = context.scene.list_bones[i].name.replace('\n','')
    return None 

def enum_list_presets_clearAllBones(self, context):
    list_bones = context.scene.list_bones
    index = context.scene.list_bones_id
    
    for i in range(len(list_bones)):
        index = context.scene.list_bones_id
        list_bones.clear()
        context.scene.list_bones_id = 0
    
    return{'FINISHED'}

class BONES_PT_ListBones(Panel):
    bl_label='Bones'
    bl_space_type='VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type='UI'
    bl_category='Bones'
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        props = context.scene.ui_props

        rows = 2
        row = layout.row()
        row.template_list('BONES_ListBones', 'The List', scene, 'list_bones', scene, 'list_bones_id')
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator('bones.reload_preset', icon="PRESET")
        
classes = [ 
    BONES_PG_ListBones,
    ListPresets,
    BONES_ListBones,
    BONES_ReloadPresets,
    BONES_PT_ListBones
    ]

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.Scene.list_bones = CollectionProperty(type = BONES_PG_ListBones)
    bpy.types.Scene.list_bones_pp = PointerProperty(type = BONES_PG_ListBones)
    bpy.types.Scene.list_presets = CollectionProperty(type = ListPresets)
    bpy.types.Scene.list_presets = PointerProperty(type = ListPresets)
    bpy.types.Scene.list_bones_id = IntProperty(name = "Index for list_bones", default = 0)
    bpy.types.Scene.active_object_index = IntProperty()
    
def unregister():
    del bpy.types.Scene.list_bones
    del bpy.types.Scene.list_bones_id
    del bpy.types.Scene.list_presets
    del bpy.types.Scene.ui_props
    
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bones_load_presets()
    register()
```

Scout.txt

```
BoneChassis_cdt
-0.967 -0.0 0.988
BoneAxle2
-1.166 -0.0 0.56
BoneExhaust
-1.761 0.315 0.725
BoneAxle1
1.411 0.0 0.56
```

Comment: can u pls post at least a code which we can test and run and not just fragments? thx

Comment: @Chris hi! I updated the post

Comment: can u pls also post a bit of data of your scout.txt?

Comment: do you know this answer here? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30444/create-an-interface-which-is-similar-to-the-material-list-box i think, this is what you are searching for.

Comment: @Chris added file

Comment: @Chris in this example, PointerProperty is used, but I would like to focus on StringProperty

Comment: Just a small typo, I think. Change **bone** to **item** in line 25: `layout.prop(item, "name", text="", emboss=False)` to access property. And please remove or comment line 129 in your example. There´s no `context.scene.ui_props` registered

Comment: @relaxed you are my hero! it worked :3