# Is it possible to add property columns to the display in a UIList?

Tags: python, add-on

For an add-on I'm working on, I followed https://sinestesia.co/blog/tutorials/using-uilists-in-blender/ to create a simple UIList. It looks like this:

[image]

This works rather nicely, except that I'd like the `PropertyGroup` properties `OpenRoof` and `Furnished` (in red squares, above) to display their values in columns next to each object's name in the list (e.g., in the empty squared locations in my JPEG). Currently, I can only see/edit these properties' values by specifically selecting an object.

I've looked through the Python API documentation for UIList but it was not clear to me if there is a way to do this.  Can the UIList display be altered to behave like I've described?

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30444/create-an-interface-which-is-similar-to-the-material-list-box  Simply add another prop to item layout.  Similarly for modifiers  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14203/15543

Comment: That worked wonderfully, thanks. Some of the code in that answer seems slightly outdated (keyword args as non-keyword args), but was very easy to adapt. Is there an appropriate way to mark this question 'closed', given you answered it in a comment rather than an answer?